# How to manually send Java traces to the OpenTelemetry collector

Tags: collectors, open-telemetry

How to create OpenTelemetry traces in Java and send to the OpenTelemetry collector manually?

Answer (score 0):

Use opentelemetry java sdk to create spans and configure exporter to send spans to opentelemetry collector
SDK available [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java)

Use the Manual instrumentation as explained [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/java/manual_instrumentation/).

Example available [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/java/instrumentation_examples/)